# Creating a dictionary class and then using those dictionaries to modify sets of numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to create a class that creates dictionaries out of sets of numbers that I'm passing in. I'm still relatively new to Python (I've only recently started to teach myself Classes) and combining dictionaries and classes is throwing me for a loop. I know for a fact a lot of my code is funky but I can't tell where I'm going wrong. Help would be appreciated.

```
class DictSet:
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.newDict = {}
        for i in elements:
            self.newDict[i] = True
    def addElement(self, x):
        self.newDict[x] = True
    def deleteElement(self, x):
        del self.newDict[x]
    def member(self, x):
        return x in self.newDict
    def intersection(self, set2):
        a = self.newDict.keys
        b = otherset.newDict.keys
        otherset = Dict({})
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if b[i] in a:
                otherset[b[i]] = True
        return newSet
    def union(self, set2):
        a = self.newDict.keys
        b = otherset.newDict.keys
        list1 = a + b
        new = DictSet(new+List)
        return new
    def subtract(self, s):
        a = self.newDict.keys
        b = otherset.newDict.keys
        set3 = Dict({})
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if b[i] not in a:
                set3[b[i]] = True
        return set3


def main():
    allints = DictSet([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    odds = DictSet([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
    evens = DictSet([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
    print("All", odds.add(evens))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend to do. All you're doing right now is creating two objects (`allints` and `odds` which both have a variable set (`self.newDict`). Could you explain what your expected output would be? You can run e.g. `allints.addElement(x=123)` and then `print allints.newDict` for example, to see this new int added. Is this what you wish to do?

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to create dictionaries (just sets of numbers really) and then be able to modify the dictionaries (i.e. adding values, subtracting values, making a union of two sets of numbers, making a new set that is an intersection of two sets, etc.) I would be able to do this fairly easily using lists but I am trying to utilize classes and dictionaries while still accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening instead? Are you getting an error message?